# create async unit test throws aggregate exception

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

What do I have to change to make this async unit run correctly?

At the moment I get an  `'System.AggregateException'`

I have read that I should not mark a test method with asnyc and prefix the SUT with 'await' because then the assertion will fail as the result is not yet returned.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateAsyncViewModel()
{
    // other stuff
    var result =  vmMapper.CreateViewModel(mock1,mock2);
    result.Wait();

    var viewModel = result.Result;

    Assert.AreEqual(viewModel.Data.Count(), 1);

}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to look inside the aggregate exception to see what the root cause is.

Comment: `"I have read that I should not mark a test method with asnyc and prefix the SUT with 'await' because then the assertion will fail as the result is not yet returned"` - Where did you read that?  Awaiting the task will do just that... await it.  The assertion won't execute until the task is completed.  As for the exception, what are the details?  What line throws the exception?  What is the inner exception of the aggregate?  "I get an exception" isn't enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @David But then my test runs synchrounously correct? because it waits...

Comment: @Pascal: If the test runner also awaits the test, yes.  But you don't really control the test runner, so that's not worth worrying about.  (Also, how would that be different from the current implementation?)  The point is that async should be "async all the way down", meaning that consuming code should also be async and it should be up to the application host to determine the synchronization of the call.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use [asynchronous unit test methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx), as I describe in an MSDN article:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task CreateAsyncViewModel()
{
  // other stuff
  var result =  vmMapper.CreateViewModel(mock1, mock2);

  var viewModel = await result;

  Assert.AreEqual(viewModel.Data.Count(), 1);
}
```

`await` will avoid the `AggregateException` wrapper, allowing you to more easily determine why your unit test is failing.

Comment: I did the unit test now without async/await by using CreateViewModel().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); Whats the difference to that to your code?

Comment: Your unit test is blocking on the asynchronous code. It's more natural to use async all the way.

Comment: But when I use the more natural way to use async on the test method, then one test might expect certain data in the database while another test has deleted this data. What about the runtime dependencies of multiple unit tests in a class?

Comment: @Pascal: The best approach is to mock out your database layer so that your tests aren't hitting the database at all. Note that with MSTest, by default all tests run *simultaneously*, regardless of whether they are synchronous or asynchronous. So even if you block, you'll run into the same problem.